# Coconvergent topology basis?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Consider the space $X=\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N_+\}$, with the "coconvergent topology":
$$\mathcal O=\{A:(A=\varnothing)\lor(\sum_{x\notin A}x<\infty)\}$$
That is, a nonempty set is open iff its complement is convergent.

- I know it's not Hausdorff, since no two nonempty open sets are disjoint (i.e. it's hyperconnected). However, points are clearly closed.
- I know that no infinite set $S$ is compact, since every infinite set has an infinite convergent subset $S'\subseteq S$, and the family $\{(X\setminus S')\cup\{1/n\}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has no finite subcover. (The characterization of compactness in terms of intersections of closed sets is easier to think about here.)

However, I'm still having trouble visualizing this space. Does it have any simple basis? That would make examining its properties a little easier.

Comment: AKA the nvergent topology.